# window.checkout is undefined

Tags: magento-2.1, error, addtocart

When I do an add to cart, nothing happens.
I have this error in the console:
*TypeError: window.checkout is undefined*

For: images.js & minicart.js

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you removed the minicart?

Comment: No...Hello,
Here's the errors I have in the console...

- SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'   on my product pages
- TypeError: window.checkout is undefined.    images.js 15:13
- TypeError: window.checkout is undefined.    authentication-popup.js 26:13
- Error:status 400. price-widget   1279:17

Comment: As I can see, the issue seem from minicart.phtml at line 42 or so. the render is like this on my home or product pages.... <script> window.checkout = ; </script>

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1458#issuecomment-268773483